# Pass CGPoint in Notification of iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, cgpoint

I want to send CGpoint to my maincontroller class. So I am using Notification to send cgpoint but I dont know how to extract from cgpoint from notification at receiver. I only get 0.00 on my log output.

Here is my code.

AT sender:

```
 NSValue *pointAsObject =[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(touchDetectingView.lastTouchPosition.x, touchDetectingView.lastTouchPosition.y)];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"swap" object:pointAsObject];
```

AT receiver Header file:

```
- (void)incomingNotification:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

At receiver M file

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(incomingNotification:) name:@"swap" object:nil];

- (void)incomingNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     NSValue *pointAsObject = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"swap"];
    NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification %f",pointAsObject.CGPointValue.y);
}
```

But I only get 0.00 OUTPUT ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)incomingNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     NSValue *pointAsObject = [notification object];
    NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification %f",pointAsObject.CGPointValue.y);
}
```

Comment: if its working then dont forget to accept it as correct answer... Thnx)

Comment: i can accept answer after 7 min of submission plz edit ur answer so other can get help